# How to get a string when using gets method in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm working on making a simple text-based tic-tac-toe game in Ruby. My game will begin by asking the user whether they want to be X or O. I'm using a variable `userSym` to store the user input. According to the documentation, `gets` returns either Nil or String ([Kernel class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-gets)). My code is not behaving properly because the userSym variable is not a String, and I can't tell why. Is there something I'm missing? Any help is appreciated!

```
puts "Welcome to TicTacRuby!"
puts "Please select your symbol. X goes first, O goes second. "

userSym = ''
begin
    userSym = Kernel.gets.match(/XO/)
rescue
    puts "Invalid input! Please enter X or O: "
else
    userSym.to_s
end

puts userSym.class
puts userSym
userSym == "X" ? first = 1 : first = 0

if first then 
    puts "You will play as #{userSym}, you will play first."
else
    puts "You will play as #{userSym}, you will play second."
end 

pamcakes-1015E:~$ ruby tictactoe.rb 
Welcome to TicTacRuby!
Please select your symbol. X goes first, O goes second. 
X
NilClass

You will play as , you will play first.
```

Comment: Change `/XO/` to `/[XO]/`. This won't fix your problem completely, but it will steer you in the right direction, as you'll see that line returns a `MatchData` object instead of `nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, `String.match` returns nil, or a `match data`.

And `userSym.to_s` returns a String that will be ignored and thus the line will not have any visible side effect.

Comment: Woops, I thought I was missing something silly. I'll be doing this instead: userSym = gets.chomp userSym.match(/[XO]/)  Thanks so much for your quick response!

Answer (score 0):

`userSym = Kernel.gets.match(/X|O/)` works.

Answer (score 0):

It's messy to use a `begin ... rescue ... end` block just to check if the user entered an O or X.  Just do

```
input = gets.strip # strip removes newline
while input !~ /^(X|O)$/
  print "Invalid input! Please enter X or O: "
  input = gets.strip
end
p input
# => "X" or "O"
```